# Small auto scrolling window

Tags: javascript

I'd like to apply a global site-wide little javascript window on the very bottom right of the site that will display a window about 40 x 80 wide, just a book icon and the word "Bible", where when a person clicks it, it will open a pop-up window, centered and pull whatever page I give it to display the bible itself (I have it internally already). These little javascript windows auto scroll as you scroll up or down the pages, you've seen them many times.

PS: I also want a "hide" option, but it doesn't hide it but minimizes it down to a small icon, all the way to the very bottom right of the site. So, click it opens, click it minimizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution lies with jquery www.jquery.com  There are (literally) thousands of scripts and you are sure to find your solution there.